# Custom jQuery dont work

Tags: jquery

I've added some jQuery code to my magento shop, to be able to make tabs ind my short desciption on my products. But it dont work.

My jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".contentMenuContent").css("display", "none");
  $(".contentMenuContent:first").show();

  $(".contentMenu").click(function() {

    $(".contentMenu").removeClass("contentMenuActive");
    $(this).addClass("contentMenuActive");

    var index = $(".contentMenu").index(this);

    $(".contentMenuContent:eq(" + index + ")").fadeOut("normal", function() {
    $(".contentMenuContent").css("display", "none");
    $(".contentMenuContent:eq(" + index + ")").fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

My short desciption

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="top"><a class="contentMenu">Uddannelse 1</a></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="top"><a class="contentMenu">Uddannelse 2</a></td>
<td style="text-align: center;" valign="top"><a class="contentMenu">Uddannelse 3</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="contentMenuContent">
<h4>Uddannelse 1 - Overskrift</h4>
HER INDS&AElig;TTER DU DIT INDHOLD <br /><br /></div>
<div class="contentMenuContent">
<h4>Uddannelse 2 - Overskrift</h4>
HER INDS&AElig;TTER DU DIT INDHOLD <br /><br /></div>
<div class="contentMenuContent">
<h4>Uddannelse 3 - Overskrift</h4>
HER INDS&AElig;TTER DU DIT INDHOLD <br /><br /></div>
```

My xml add - (I can se in my header that it is added)

```
<action method="addJs"><script>puk/contentmenu.js</script></action>
```

Comment: Check your inspect it's call frontend or not

Comment: can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Is there any errors in the console? Also what is your exact path to your `contentmenu.js` Also do you have jQuery Installed?

Comment: You know front end inspect element right? check there it show your script or not

Comment: Åhh yeah. its there.@Kothari
@rob3000 Path is /public_html/js/puk/contentmenu.js. And yeah its installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are using `$` as shortcut, which is usually owned by default JS library in Magento (prototype). Are you using `noConflict()` function, to avoid problems with Prototype?

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/